# how can I cherry pick from upstream to my fork

Tags: github

I am very new in git hub my apologies for this naive question
I just forked a repository and I want to cherry pick from the original repo to my fork
here is what I did

```
git cherry pick 9fb44607a2ae89fb5b3a6b81sssdfsdadb0ec5
```

but I got this error

> fatal: Unknown commit 9fb44607a2ae89fb5b3a6b81sssdfsdadb0ec5

what is the proper command to do such action

thank you

Comment: `git fetch` then cherry pick.

Comment: @bishop still getting same error - I just forked tho .. why need to do git fetch?

Comment: So, your commit has four 's' in it. Hashes are hex characters only. So check your hash again.

Comment: @bishop well this is not a real hash :) just made that up .. but I am using real hash when I run the command

Answer (score 3):

> but I am using real hash when I run the command

If that real hash:

- come from the upstream repository (the one you have forked)
- has been created *after* your fork

You would then need to fetch from upstream in order for that commit to be present in your local repository (clone of your fork).

```
cd /path/to/my/cloned/fork
git remote add upstream https://url/original/repository
git fetch upstream
```

Then you can cherry-pick that SHA1.